# Area of the surface on a sphere surrounded by three externally tangent circles?

Tags: integration, geometry, spherical-geometry

Let us draw three circles of radius $\dfrac23$ on a sphere of radius $1$, all of which are mutually tangent (externally).

How do I calculate the area of the surface surrounded by the three circles?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $r_1, r_2, r_3$ be the center of the three circles. Let $\triangle$ be the spherical triangle formed by $r_1, r_2, r_3$. It's known that it's a equilateral triangle with side length $\frac 43$. Using the [cosine formula on the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Cosine_rules), we have

$$(*)\ \ \ \ \ \cos \left( 4/3\right) = \cos \left( 4/3\right)\cos \left( 4/3\right) + \sin\left( 4/3\right)\sin \left( 4/3\right) \cos A,$$

where $A$ is the angle (all three angles are the same) of $\triangle$. Now the area of the shaded $C$ is found by

$$\text{Area}(C) = \text{Area}(\triangle) - 3\text{Area}(B),$$

where $B$ is the sector with radius $2/3$ and angle $A$. Both of them can be calculated: we have

$$B = \int_0^{2/3} \int_0^A \sin r d\theta dr= A(1-\cos 2/3),$$

and

$$\text{Area}(\triangle)= (A + A+ A - \pi).$$

Thus

$$\begin{split} \text{Area}(C) &= 3A - \pi -  3 A(1-\cos 2/3) \\
&= 3A \cos 2/3 - \pi
\end{split}$$

Numnerically, its around [0.11](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+arccos%28%28cos%284%2F3%29+-+cos%5E2%284%2F3%29%29%2Fsin%5E2%284%2F3%29%29cos%282%2F3%29+-+%5Cpi).

Comment: +1 Great, now I can upvote this ( it matches what I have, up to interpretation of what the radius mean but that is up to the OP to clarify).